# OAuth 2.0 with Implict Grant type Spring boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-rest

We are building an application with following tech specs decided.

- Angular 4/5 [Front End]
- SpringBoot Framework [BackEnd]
- OAuth 2.0 [Authorization]
- MySQL [Database]

> **Note :** We ourselves are having Resource Server, Authorization Server

---

**Flow**

We provide a single instance application for multiple clients [our clients], who will have their own users. Every user will get an email to authorize some stuff for their respective clients via our application. The email link will contain client_id, record_id encrypted and encoded. When the user clicks on the link, it should go to AuthServer, authorize the client via its client_id, and pass back the token to the user agent, to make any further operations.

We went through this **[Github repo](https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot)** and implemented the same as the sample.

The AuthServer `Configure` code is as below:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
       clients.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")
             .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code",
                            "refresh_token", "implicit")
             .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
             .scopes("read", "write", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
             .accessTokenValiditySeconds(60).and()
             .withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")
      .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code").authorities("ROLE_CLIENT")
             .scopes("read", "trust").resourceIds("sparklr")
             .redirectUris("http://anywhere?key=value").and()
             .withClient("my-client-with-secret")
             .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials", "password")
                    .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT").scopes("read").resourceIds("sparklr")
             .secret("secret");

}
```

We have some doubts on the values passed to the configure method.

- What does `.inMemory().withClient("my-trusted-client")` represent here? Will this always be hardcoded? Since we would be validating each client based on the client_id received, where will we feed this to validate dynamically?
- What is `.withClient("my-client-with-registered-redirect")` for? Even this remains constant for every client?
- The author in the repo has also said that we can validate the setup via 
  `$ curl -H "Accept: application/json" my-client-with-secret:secret@localhost:8080/oauth/token -d grant_type=client_credentials` and I see `my-client-with-secret:secret` passed here. If this is going to be changed for different clients how can I give this value to `.withClient("my-client-with-secret")` and `.secret("secret")`

We are totally tough time understanding these concepts. Our requirement is simple, *We are going to validate every client with client_id and generate a token for that client*. Do we need to have any other `Grant_types` for this type of requirements?

Someone please point us in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First question:**
In your example, the clients are hardcoded (hence the `clients.inMemory()`). You can configure a datasource and use that:

```
@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients.jdbc(dataSource); // Get clients from database, table = oauth_client_details
}
```

You can find more info in the [documentation](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

**Second question** In the example, three clients are configured:

1. `my-trusted-client`: this client can authorize using these OAuth2 flows: `"password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit"`
2. `my-client-with-registered-redirect`: this client can authorize using these OAuth2 flows: `"authorization_code"`
3. `my-client-with-secret`: this client can authorize using these OAuth2 flows: `"client_credentials"`

You need to understand the difference between these flows.

**Third question** if you want to use other clients, you must add them in your code/database

Comment: Thank you so much.. It cleared most of the doubts... :)